# How do I match the hash from JS API to that displayed in the UI

Tags: polkadot-js

I am trying to programatically construct the hash as used for multisig transactions, basically the [approveAsMulti](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics#approveasmultithreshold-u16-other_signatories-vecaccountid32-maybe_timepoint-optionpalletmultisigtimepoint-call_hash-u832-max_weight-u64) which taking a call hash.

So my code is along the following form,

```js
/* create the tx */
const inner = api.tx.balances.transfer('1G...', 100000000)

/* generate the hash */
const hash = inner.hash

/* generate the approval */
const multi = api.tx.multisig.approveAsMulti(2, ['1G...', ...], null, hash, weight)

/* send it here ... */
...
```

However the hash I generate is not the same hash as what I can see in the UI, so right at the end I cannot actually seem to approve the final step via the UI. So I'm not sure what goes wrong, the hashes should match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short version: for the call-only part, use `inner.method.hash`.

(I'll use your same `inner` naming throughout.)

The longer version: The `api.tx` construct is representative of an extrinsic, initially when it is created, it is unsigned, once we use `inner.signAsync(...)` (or `inner.signAndSubmit(...)`), it is signed. So when you call `inner.hash`, you actually retrieve the (initially unsigned) extrinsic hash.

Internally an extrinsic represented here has two major parts,

- the signature (comprising the signing address, actual cryptographic signature and all data from the signed extensions as per the metadata definition)
- the call (pallet/method index and call data as per metadata)

So after all of this: For the hash of the call-only, access the call via the `.method` getter and then the `.hash` on that will return the hash for the call only.

Comment: Thank you for the detail.